# mac os switch to another svn branch in a workspace

Tags: macos, svn, branch

Have 8 projects in my workspace all in the same svn main project

> svn://serverA/svn/SVNROOT/projectT/trunk/

Have made a branch using svn copy to

> svn://serverA/svn/SVNROOT/projectT/branch/v1

Now I want to use this branch. Using mac os - > is there any easy way or recursive script I can use to change the svn branch in all my projects .svn files ?

OR in windows can use tortise is there a similar UI for Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** switch your Working Copy of trunk to the new URL (of created branch), using OS-independent *svn-command*.

Read [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) description in SVN Book or more detailed explanation of process in ["Traversing Branches"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.switchwc.html) topic

Comment: thhank you, i though that was tool dependanct, my searches took me to the wrong place